# How to model the gravity of Titan in GMAT

Tags: trajectory, interplanetary, titan, gmat, saturn

I would like to know how to find the gravity file (.cof) for Saturn's moon Titan. Need this to model the gravity field of Titan.

Comment: FWIW, its GM is 8978.14 km^3/s^2 https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&MAKE_EPHEM=NO&COMMAND=606

Answer (score 6):

A google search for "saturn titan gravity field" turns up [Durante et al. 2019](http://douglashemingway.com/publications/Durante2019.pdf).  Its Table 2 lists coefficients up to degree 5.